# Redeploy ignite cluster with FailedMount or Failed to start GridManagerAdapter errors

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, persistence, ignite, kubernetes-pvc

I have the ignite cluster with 2 nodes deployed on GKE, with persistence enabled for default region and have pvc and I am testing the data persistence.

When I first deploy the cluster and no data records is written into the cache, I can redeploy the cluster without any issue. Once I write one record into the cache and then tear down the cluster and redeploy it (without deleting pvc), I would always get two kind of errors:

1. stuck on creating container step and got FailedMount:

`MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-1a83b66a-8be9-49bc-b015-4e4b5b237e37" : applyFSGroup failed for vol projects/UNSPECIFIED/zones/xxx/disks/pvc-1a83b66a-8be9-49bc-b015-4e4b5b237e37: readdirent /var/lib/kubelet/pods/ae17e40c-c924-4d38-a232-c4b853ffb1ae/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-1a83b66a-8be9-49bc-b015-4e4b5b237e37/mount: input/output error`

2. node 1 start without issue, but node 2 got crush back off error and log showed:

`Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]`

`class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI:`

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]`

Here is the part of config in statefulset related to pvc:

```
      containers:
        - name: ignite-node
          image: "gridgain/community:8.8.19"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
          {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          env:
            - name: OPTION_LIBS
              value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http,control-center-agent
            - name: CONFIG_URI
              value: file:///opt/ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
            - name: JVM_OPTS
              value: "-DIGNITE_WAL_MMAP=false \
                     -DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true \
                     - ...."
          ports:
            - containerPort: ...
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: opt/ignite/config
            name: config-vol
          - mountPath: opt/ignite/work
            name: work-vol
          - mountPath: opt/ignite/wal
            name: wal-vol
          - mountPath: opt/ignite/walarchive
            name: walarchive-vol


  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: work-vol
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "1G"
    - metadata:
        name: wal-vol
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "1G"
    - metadata:
        name: walarchive-vol
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "1G"
```

Comment: Hi, could you share you kubernetes deployment config. Do you use StatefulSet for Ignite nodes with persistence?

Comment: yeah, I use statefulset, I added the config above